# how is main page of wordpress website loaded?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I want to edit some code of main page of my WordPress website. where can I find the code for main page in c Panel in file manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on your website and inspect element then at the top you can find `"<body class="your home page name">"`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Wordpress theme.

It should be **wp-content/themes/your-theme/index.php** or **wp-content/themes/your-theme/page-main.php**